# Sort Dictionary based on values in a list of integers

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a problem sorting a dictionary based on the sum of 1s in lists of integers inside the same Dictionary. So first I want to count the 1s in each list and then sort the dictionary based on the result. 
I've found some solutions in Stackoverflow but they don't answer my question.

Th dictionary looks like the following:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> myDic = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList = new List<int>();//Should appear third
myList.Add(0);
myList.Add(0);
myList.Add(1);
myDic.Add(0, myList);

myList = new List<int>();//Should appear second
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(0);
myDic.Add(1, myList);

myList = new List<int>();//Should appear first
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(1);
myDic.Add(2, myList);
```

I tried this code but it seems it doesn't do anything.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>> myList2 = myDic.ToList();
myList2.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
 {
     return firstPair.Value.Where(i=>i==1).Sum().CompareTo(nextPair.Value.Where(x=>x==1).Sum());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting list items in ascending order. I.e. items with more 1s will go to the end of list. You should use descending order. Just compare nextPair to firstPair (or change sign of comparison result):

```
myList2.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
 {
     return nextPair.Value.Where(i => i==1).Sum().CompareTo(
                  firstPair.Value.Where(x => x==1).Sum());
});
```

This approach has one problem - sum of 1s in value will be calculated each time two items are compared. Better use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`. It's more simple to use, and it will compute comparison values (i.e. keys) only once. Thus Dictionary is a enumerable of KeyValuePairs, you can use OrderByDescending directly with dictionary:

```
var result = myDic.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value.Where(i => i == 1).Sum());
```

Comment: This is no different from the OP's code.  It's simpler, but it doesn't answer his question of why his code isn't doing what he expects it to.

Answer (score 1):

Your sort is backward, which is why you think it's not doing anything. Reverse the firstPair/nextPair values in your lambda and you'll get the result you expect.

Though, @Sergey Berezovskiy is correct, you could just use OrderBy, your example code could benefit from perhaps a different pattern overall.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SummedKV
{
    public KeyValuePair Kvp {get; set;}
    public int Sum {get; set;}
}

var myList  =
         myDic.ToList()
              .Select(kvp=> new SummedKV {Kvp = kvp, Sum = kvp.Value.Sum() });
myList.Sort(skv=>skv.Sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simpler

```
myList2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Sum());
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code does do something.  it creates a list of the items that used to be in the dictionary, sorted based on the number of `1` items contained in the list.  The code that you have correctly creates this list and sorts it as your requirements say it should.  (Note that using `OrderByDescending` would let you do the same thing more simply.)

It has no effect on the dictionary that you pulled the lists out of, of course.  Dictionaries are unordered, so you can't "reorder" the items even if you wanted to.  If it were some different type of ordered collection then it would be *possible* to change the order of it's items, but just creating a new structure and ordering *that* wouldn't do it; you'd need to use some sort of operation on the collection itself to change the order of the items.

Comment: OP has pretty valid code, the problem is ascending sorting. He needs descending one, and OrderBy is not good choice

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy He's trying to re-order the dictionary.  That won't happen.  Dictionaries are not ordered.  The use of `OrderBy` is entirely tangential from the actual answer here.

Comment: Who says about re-ordering dictionary? OP tries to sort list.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy The OP did, in the title of his question, in his first sentence, and in his second sentence.

Comment: All the answers here and none of them really address the problem of his sort was just backwards :P Sometimes I feel bad for poor people asking questions. They will re-write their code to be awesome, and have the same problem, and never learn what the original problem was. :)